# Vue select dropdown from MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vue.js, model-view-controller, dropdown, viewmodel

I'm trying to use vue istance with MVC, but I get an error:

**[Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.**

I created MVC Controller in order to get View with a ViewModel:

**ViewModel**

```
public class HomeViewModel
{
    public string JumbotronTitle { get; set; }
    public string JumbotronDescription { get; set; }
    public List<int> Numbers { get; set; }
}
```

**HomeController**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var vm = new HomeViewModel
        {
            JumbotronTitle = "Title from view model",
            JumbotronDescription = "Description from view model",
            Numbers = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 }
        };
        return View(vm);
    }
}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@using WebApplication_VueJS.Models
@model HomeViewModel

<div class="jumbotron" id="jumbotron-section" :initialJumboValues='setJumbotronValues(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)))' v-cloak>    
    <select class="form-control" v-model="selected">
        <option v-for="number in jumbotronObj.Numbers" :value="number">{{ number }}</option>
    </select>
    <span>Test: {{ selected }}</span>
</div>

<script>
    new Vue({
        el: '#jumbotron-section',
        data: {
            initialJumboValues: '',
            jumbotronObj: {},
            selected: null,
        },
        methods: {
            setJumbotronValues: function (vm) {
                this.jumbotronObj = vm;                
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

The Dropdown works but in console I have this error. How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance

R1